# add method to a class dynamically with decorator

Tags: python, methods, decorator

I would have add method to a `class` dynamically... function name will also passed dynamically.

How can i do? I tried in this way

```
def decor(*var):
  def onDecorator(aClass):
    class onInstance:
        def __init__(self,*args,**kargs):
            setter=var
            aClass.setter = self.flam
            self.wrapped = aClass(*args,**kargs)

        def __getattr__(self,attr):
            return getattr(self.wrapped,attr)

        def __setattr__(self,attr,value):
            if attr == 'wrapped':
                self.__dict__[attr]=value
            else:
                setattr(self.wrapped,attr,value)

        def flam(self,*args):
            self.__setattr__('dimension',len(args[0]))

    return onInstance
return onDecorator
```

but if i do:

```
print(aClass.__dict__)
```

i have

```
'setter': <bound method onInstance.flam of <__main__.onInstance object at 0x522270>>
```

instead of `var`:.....

i have this class:

```
class D:
  def __init__(self, data):
    self.data = data
    self.dimension = len(self.data)
```

i would call:

```
D.name()
```

and have back `self.dimension` but i don't know `name` in advance

Comment: Show an example of the code that you hope to use to attach the method to the class. I have no idea how you could have a method that you want to attach, but not have any kind of name for it. I also have no idea how you expect the method to make any sense to be attached to the class, if the class wasn't designed with that method in the first place.

Comment: Years later, but showing a good and simple solution: https://medium.com/@mgarod/dynamically-add-a-method-to-a-class-in-python-c49204b85bd6

Answer (score 17):

This is my decorator

```
def decorator(name):
    def wrapper(K):
        setattr(K, name, eval(name))
        return K
    return wrapper
```

This is a sample method

```
def myfunc(self):
    print "Istance class: ", self
```

This is a decoreted class

```
@decorator("myfunc")
class Klass:
    pass
```

I hope this is useful and what you need :)

Answer (score 7):

Here's a simplified py3 solution

```
class A(object):
    def a(self):
        print('a')

def add_b(cls):
    def b(self):
        print('b')

    setattr(cls, 'b', b)
    return cls

@add_b
class C(A):
    pass

C().b() # 'b'
```

Comment: This is the most elegant of all solutions here

Answer (score 1):

```
def add_method(cls):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        setattr(cls, func.__name__, wrapper)
        return func
    return decorator
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
class Foo:
    pass

@add_method(Foo)
def bar(self, parameter1):
    pass # Do something where self is a class instance
```

Just remember to have self parameter in a function which you want to add to a class.

Answer (score 0):

```
def dec(cls):
    setattr(cls, 'c', 0)    # add atr counter to CLS

    def __init__(self):
        cls.c += 1  # +1 to CLS, not self!

    def get_c(self=None):
        return cls.c    # get current value from CLS


    setattr(cls, '__init__', __init__)  # add new __init__ IT WILL OVERWRITE original __init__
    setattr(cls, 'get_c', get_c)    # add new method
    return cls

@dec
class A:
    pass

print(A.c) # 0
user, _, _ = A(), A(), A()
user.get_c()  # 3
```

if you'd like to save the original **init** and add new value to def **init**

```
def __init__(self):
    cls.c += 1  # +1 to CLS, not self!
    cls.__init__
```