# Python3.10 decorator confusion: how to wrap a class to augment a class's __init__ e.g. to track function calls

Tags: python, python-decorators

I'm getting myself confused with python decorators. Yes, there are a lot of useful resources out there (and I have consulted them prior to posting)

e.g.

- [How can I use named arguments in a decorator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627501/how-can-i-use-named-arguments-in-a-decorator)
- [add method to a class dynamically with decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443725/add-method-to-a-class-dynamically-with-decorator)
- [functools.update_wrapper](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.update_wrapper)
- [object wrapper recipe](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/577555-object-wrapper-class/)

I am sure there are better ways to do what I am about to describe, that is because this is just a simple toy example to understand the properties not what I am actually trying to do.

Suppose you have a class

```py
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def call_me(self, arg):
        return arg
```

and I want to extend `foo`'s constructor to take in two keyword arguments and modify the `call_me` method e.g. the desired end class would be:

```py
class foo:
    def __init__(self, keep_track:bool=False, do_print:bool=True):
        self.keep_track = keep_track
        self.memory = []
        ...

    def call_me(self, arg):
        arg = self.old_call_me(arg)
        
        if self.do_print:
            print('hi')

        if self.keep_track:
             self.memory.append(arg)
       
        return arg

    def old_call_me(self, arg):
        ...
        return arg
```

Ideally, I would like a decorator  so that I can wrap a bunch of classes which I am **assuming**  have a method `call_me` like

```py
@keep_track(do_print=False) # <--- sets default state
class foo:
   ...

@keep_track(keep_track=True) # <--- sets default state
class bar:
   ...


foo_instance = foo(do_print=True) # <-- I can change behavior of instance
```

How can I achieve this?

I have tried defining functions inside the decorator and setting them with

```py
setattr(cls, 'old_call_me', call_me)
def call_me(self, arg):
    # see above
 
setattr(cls, 'call_me', call_me)
```

and using `functools.wrap`

I would appreciate the guidance in this matter.

Comment: Why not creating a subclass sub_foo who inherite of class foo ?

Comment: @Tourelou I thought about that. It is a good idea. It is because I want this functionality to be portable without having to define a subclass or if one can use a decorator to specify subclass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can offer a very, **very** convoluted, hard to read and only intended for learning purposes idea...

You *could* leverage the fact that if you try to access an instance's attribute, Python will first go look for it in the instance attributes (let's say `self.__dict__`), and if it doesn't find it there, it will try to find it in the instance's class attributes (let's say `self.__class__.__dict__`)

So you *could* have your decorator write the default into the **class** itself and then accept it as an optional keyword argument to your `__init__` method (basically creating only sometimes the `do_print` **instance** attribute).

```py
from functools import wraps


def my_decorator(*, do_print):
    def my_decorator_inner(klass):
        print(f"Outer: {do_print}")

        @wraps(klass)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print(f"Inner: {klass} {args}, {kwargs}")
            klass.do_print = do_print
            return klass(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper

    return my_decorator_inner


@my_decorator(do_print=False)
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, *, do_print=None):
        if do_print is not None:
            self.do_print = do_print

    def call_me(self):
        if self.do_print:
            print('hi')
        else:
            print("nopes, I ain't printing")


f_no_print = Foo()
f_no_print.call_me()

f_print = Foo(do_print = True)
f_print.call_me()
```

Note that I added a couple of `print` statements that might help with what's being passed to each function.

**HOWEVER** this solution is very, very convoluted and confusing when what it is really doing is just:

```py
class Foo:
    do_print = False

    def __init__(self, *, do_print=None):
        if do_print is not None:
            self.do_print = do_print

    def call_me(self):
        if self.do_print:
            print('hi')
        else:
            print("nopes, I ain't printing")


f_no_print = Foo()
f_no_print.call_me()

f_print = Foo(do_print=True)
f_print.call_me()
```

---

**EDIT** as per comments below:

In Python everything is an object. Even functions are just... sort of *"""variables"""*. And classes are objects too. When you type `class Foo:`, you are not "just" creating a class definition (well... you are, but...) you are creating an instance called `Foo` whose type is `type`. You can alter that through metaclasses (which is where the `__new__` method is **usually** used in). That object `Foo` of type `type` can then be called (`inst = Foo()`) to produce instances of type `Foo`

So, first things first. The *cleaner* subclassing method that @Tourelou was suggesting in his comment I imagine would go something like this:

```py
class Foo:
    def call_me(self, arg):
        return arg


class FooPrinting(Foo):
    def __init__(self, keep_track: bool = False, do_print: bool = True):
        self.keep_track = keep_track
        self.do_print = do_print
        self.memory = []

    def call_me(self, arg):
        arg = super().call_me(arg)
        if self.do_print:
            print(f'hi {arg}')
        if self.keep_track:
            self.memory.append(arg)
        return arg


f_no_print = Foo()
f_no_print.call_me(1)

f_print = FooPrinting(do_print=True)
f_print.call_me(2)
```

That's good, that's clean, that's probably what you'd wanna use...

You mentioned in your comment that

> Having only some instances have the keyword arg seems too non-pythonic

Actually, that is the Pythonic way. I understand it can look cluttered at first, but if you want to keep the ability of changing the behavior for some instances, you'll have to accept the parameter in the constructor somehow. And kwargs with default values are a good way of doing it. True, true: you don't really **have to** accept the parameters in the constructor, because you can dynamically add attributes to any instance at any point in your code... but you **should**. The fact you CAN do something doesn't mean you SHOULD do it (this last line is also applicable to what comes below):

Now, since you seem to just want to sort of monkey-patch a method, there's the option of dynamically swapping the class' `.call_me` method by another method (`new_call_me` in the example below) that you have "kept in the freezer" and that you swap in the decorator:

```py
from functools import wraps


def new_call_me(self, arg):
    arg = self.old_call_me(arg)
    if getattr(self, 'do_print', False):
        print(f'swapped hi {arg}')
    if getattr(self, 'keep_track', False):
        self.memory.append(arg)
    return arg


def my_decorator(*, do_print):
    def my_decorator_inner(klass):
        print(f"Outer: {do_print}")

        @wraps(klass)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print(f"Inner: {klass} {args}, {kwargs}")
            klass.do_print = do_print

            if (not (hasattr(klass, 'old_call_me'))  # <- If already swapped, skip
                    and hasattr(klass, 'call_me') and callable(klass.call_me)):
                print(f"Swapping method in class {klass.__name__}")
                klass.old_call_me = klass.call_me
                klass.call_me = new_call_me
            return klass(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper

    return my_decorator_inner


@my_decorator(do_print=True)
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, *, do_print=None):
        self.do_print = do_print

    def call_me(self, arg):
        return arg


f_no_print = Foo()
f_no_print.call_me(1)

f_print = Foo(do_print=True)
f_print.call_me(2)
```

⚠️ **HOWEVER:** If I ever see this in my company's codebase, I'd yell. And if I have any saying in the matter, I'd try to get the author of such aberration fired. Ok, fine, FINE!... maybe not so much, 'cuz I am a softie at heart , but for sure there'd be a conversation (a CON-VER-SA-TION!) with that person.

Comment: thank you for the information! So I suppose then I have two quick follow ups given your expertise. Is it better to do it this way rather than abusing `__new__`  (like `numpy` does)? I know that another user (Tourelou) suggested just subclassing. Is there a decorator way to do subclassing? Having only some instances have the keyword arg seems too non-pythonic even for a janky, learning example. Or do you have a better idea for most easily allowing a user augment args, attrs, methods of a class while specifying defaults with as minimal boilerplate (like decorators)

Comment: @SumNeuron, added an "Edit" 

Comment: @SumNeuron, Thanks for the acceptance. Jokes on my edit aside, Python has AMAZING introspection and dynamic code writing capabilities. I've said for years that it's a language that _"can dynamically rewrite itself"_. It is fun to play with and see what it can do (take a look at the `inspect` module, for instance). However, the more "magic" the less readability. This happens a lot with ML-oriented libraries (pandas, numpy...) They do "a lot" under the hood. That's fine, but, generally speaking, I've grown to greatly value code readability. But by all means, play with them. It's very cool.  

Comment: I appreciate your detailed and layman's explanation :) I also like readability which is why I was looking at the decorator option, because with something like PyTorch's `nn.Module` inheriting two classes  can be problematic (if both are `nn.Module`) and using a decorator just seems cleaner